# "Update.log" size increase all the time

Tags: cron, crontab, magento-2.1.4

Every body, I got a problem --
My var/log.update.log is keeping increasing.
And that cause me lot of trouble.

I found this issue and try to stop log by change cron job into:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/php/bin/php /home/wwwroot/shopkey.doyustudio.com/bin/magento cron:run
* * * * * /usr/local/php/bin/php /home/wwwroot/shopkey.doyustudio.com/update/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/local/php/bin/php /home/wwwroot/shopkey.doyustudio.com/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

But it not working.
update.log is keep increasing, and that's totally useless for trouble shooting.
I found a topic is talking about how to trace it.
But I don't wan't to edit magento system, is there any other way to disable to log?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the web setup wizard to update or install Magento extensions from the admin panel, you can remove `update/cron.php` entirely from your crontab. It's probably not working anyways if it logs that much.